# output of psExec in Powershell is not captured

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am new to powershell. I have below ps script file:

```
$Output = psExec -accepteula -n 60 -d \\xxx c:\xxx.exe "..."
write-output $output
```

But seems $output is empty and outout of PsExec is not captured. How do I do this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: `psExec` and redirection of input and output streams is a whole world of pain... However, what happens if you wrap the command in an `Invoke-Expression`?

Comment: I only use psexec when I don't have powershell. Why not just do powershell remoting the correct way?

Comment: At a pinch, you could shell out to CMD to run the PsExec, redirect output to temp file, then pull that back into PS.

Comment: @Cole9350 I want to use PS native remote mechanism like Invoke-Command but remote server doesn't allow WMI communication so can't do that.

Comment: @Sheen what exactly does Invoke-Command have to do with WMI? And where are you finding this information

Comment: @Cole9350 I find that I need to run "winrm quickconfig" on remote server before I can Invoke-Command on it.

Comment: @Sheen, yes you definitely would need to enable PSremoting. I'd take a look here http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_psexec_wrapper